# como incluir librerias externas en Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, aplicación-web

normalmente cuando uno esta haciendo una web las librerías se incluyen así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.css"

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js"></script>
```

Pero en Ionic la estructura del documento es diferente, alguien sabe como puedo incluir estas librerías en un proyecto de Ionic

Comment: ¿Es una librería/módulo que existe en node? ¿O algo que te has descargado de Internet o una librería propia?

Comment: es una librería de animaciones con javascritp que encontré en Internet

Comment: Parece que esa librería está en node. Prueba a hacer `npm install aos --save` y creo que debería instalarse directamente sin necesidad de hacer mucho más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la librería/modulo existe en npm ([como parece que es el caso para aos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos)), tan sólo tendrías que ir al directorio de tu proyecto y ejecutar el siguiente comando (como se indica en las [instrucciones](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos#-setup)):

```
npm install aos --save
```

Eso debería descargarse los ficheros necesarios y añadir las dependencias en los ficheros de configuración.

---

Si es una librería que te has descargado, entonces la idea general es que tienes que poner las librerías descargadas en la estructura de tu proyecto y para luego importar esas copias locales en lugar de copias a librerías online.

Los pasos a seguir serían algo como esto:

1. Crea tu proyecto con ionic
2. Navega al directorio `src/assets` de tu proyecto
3. Crea un directorio para el JS y CSS (por ejemplo los directorios `js` y `css`)
4. Abre para editar tu index.html (debería estar directamente en el directorio `src`)

   1. Añade la referencia al JS: `<script src="assets/js/tu.js></script>`
   2. Añade la referencia al CSS: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/tu.css" />`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, realmente me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo si usas npm usa este comando

- `npm install aos --save`

Si estas usando yarn

- `yarn add aos`

Lo instalará y lo añadirá a tu package.json

Te dejo este link de referencia
[Install](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#install-aos)

Answer (score 1):

Pues lo que puedes hacer es ingresar los links en tu archivo "index.html"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.css">
```

Este archivo lo puede encontrar en la raíz de tu proyecto, por ejemplo yo lo tengo en esta ubicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te pueda ayudar.